# "index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders) index". PDF fileendings

Tags: python, pdf, anaconda, python-unicode, langchain

I am successfully answering questions from multiple PDFs on my M1 mac. But having some issues with certain pdfs.

I am running anaconda with Langchain. The PDFs are variable sizes from 100K to 3meg. The Juypiter Notepad gets an error when running is: "index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders) index"

The error which stops SOME files from being loaded is:
"Ignoring (part of) ToUnicode map because the PDF data does not conform to the format. This could result in (cid) values in the output. The start and end byte have different lengths."

The other error which is fine:
"detectron2 is not installed. Cannot use the hi_res partitioning strategy. Falling back to partitioning with the fast strategy."

1. Is there a python or (M1MAC) Unix command to fix the unicode endings in the pdf?
2. Is there a way to get a report on which pdf is causing the error?

Thanks

Full code below.

```
-
#!pip install langchain
#!pip install unstructured
#!pip install openai
#!pip install chromadb
#!pip install Cython
#!pip install tiktoken

-
#load required packages
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

-
# set the openai key
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

#your files
pdf_folder_path = "/Users/.../Documents/.../testpdfs"

#set the pdf folder path change this!!!
## pdf_folder_path = f'{root_dir}/data/'
## os.listdir(pdf_folder_path)

# loacation of the pdf file/files
#location of the pdf file/files.
loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, fn)) for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path)]


#vector stores
#ImportError: Following dependencies are missing: pdfminer. Please install them using `pip install unstructured[local-inference]`.
#Chroma as vectorstore to index and search embeddings
#There are three main steps going on after the documents are loaded:
##Splitting documents into chunks
##Creating embeddings for each document
##Storing documents and embeddings in a vectorstore

index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders)
index

#questions
%%time
#query
index.query_with_sources('Tell me about xyz')
```

I know very little about python, and I know some find it easy and others do not.
I expected an error to show which pdf was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation when I was building something. What I did for this case is that I created a function that will process the PDFs using the same base source that `UnstructuredPDFLoader` uses:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
try:
   pdf_reader = PdfReader(f)
            for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
                page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]


except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error processing file {pdf}: {str(e)} -- file Excluded from analysis")
```

You can use this bit as a function and loop through the files so you can find the ones that have issues. Probably create a list and save them (or only save the ones working).

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think you were trying to do embedding your PDF file into VectorStore. One option you can do is, with using `document_loaders` and `text_splitter` functions to process PDF documents before inserting the doc into VectorStore

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader, DirectoryLoader
# Place PDF under /tmp
loader = DirectoryLoader('/tmp/', glob="./*.pdf")
documents = loader.load()

from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000,
                                               chunk_overlap=200)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)


# Using HF model for embedding as an example
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")

#Place vectorDB under /tmp. It can be anywhere else
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
persist_directory = "/tmp/chromadb"
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, embedding=embeddings,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure that all files in the folder are pdf.

try this:

```py
loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, fn)) for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path) if fn.endswith('.pdf')]
```

this would avoid loading hidden files created by your OS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).